# How to avoid BREACH attacks in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, ssl, csrf

I've been reading about the [BREACH attack](http://breachattack.com/) and, despites that is an attack that involves a web application in a server level too, I was wondering if there's something to block these kind of attacks in Rails.
I've found [breach-mitigation-rails](https://github.com/meldium/breach-mitigation-rails) that they say is not a bullet-proof solution, just to mitigate an attack in someways. Something else around there?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The presenters of BREACH have put up [a website with further details](http://breachattack.com/). The listed mitigations, ordered by effectiveness, are:

1. Disabling HTTP compression
2. Separating secrets from user input
3. Randomizing secrets per request
4. Masking secrets
5. Protecting vulnerable pages with CSRF
6. Length hiding
7. Rate-limiting requests

HTTP compression can fairly easily be disabled at the server, at the expense of efficiency.

The [breach-mitigation-rails gem](https://github.com/meldium/breach-mitigation-rails) addresses points #4 and #6. It is likely to break caching and increase page size.

[Another interesting fix](https://gist.github.com/homakov/6147227) works on point #4, with none of the negative impacts on efficiency, but it does require javascript (which can help cut down on spam submissions, anyway).

An [official fix is also being discussed](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/11729).

You may also find this non-rails-specific question interesting - https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/39925/breach-a-new-attack-against-http-what-can-be-done.

Answer (score -1):

Nice partial solution for rails:

http://blog.meldium.com/home/2013/8/2/running-rails-defend-yourself-against-breach

https://github.com/meldium/breach-mitigation-rails

Comment: Oops, I missed a link in the original answer, sorry for the duplication.